# Не формируется CSV файл в коде на Python, почему?

Tags: python, csv

Не формируется CSV файл в коде на Python, кто знает в чём ошибка подскажите.

```
import bs4
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.headless = True # скрывает морду браузеру
while True:
    with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option) as driver:  # Открываем хром
        driver.get("https://www.bestchange.ru/list.html")  # Открываем страницу
        time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        block = soup.find('table', id='content_table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')
        time.sleep(3)
        # print(len(block))
        for i in block:
            print('\n')
            try:
                name = i.find('div', class_='ca')
                print('Обменнк:' + ' ' + name.text.strip())
                obmen = (name.text.strip())
            except:
                continue
            try:
                work = i.find('td', class_='bj bp')
                print('Статус:' + ' ' + work.text.strip())
                status = (work.text.strip())
            except:
                continue
            try:
                bidaq = i.find_all('td', class_='ar arp')
                print('Резервы:' + ' ' + bidaq[1].text.strip())
                reserv = (bidaq[1].text.strip())
                print('Курс:' + ' ' + bidaq[2].text.strip())
                kurs = (bidaq[2].text.strip())
                print('WMBL:' + ' ' + bidaq[3].text.strip())
                wmbl = (bidaq[3].text.strip())
                print('ACTS:' + ' ' + bidaq[4].text.strip())
                acts = (bidaq[4].text.strip())
                print('PMTC' + ' ' + bidaq[5].text.strip())
                pmtc = (bidaq[5].text.strip())

                block_2 = i.find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find_all('td')
                print(len(block_2))
            except:
                continue
    print('Нажмите Enter для продолжения...')
    input()


    # block_2 = i.find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find_all('td')
    # print(len(block_2))

    storfge = {'name': obmen, 'status': status, 'reserv': reserv, 'kurs': kurs, 'wmbl': wmbl, 'acts': acts,
               'pmtc': pmtc}

    with open('example.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-16') as file:
        pisar = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        pisar.writerow([storfge['name'],
                        storfge['status'],
                        storfge['reserv'],
                        storfge['kurs'],
                        storfge['wmbl'],
                        storfge['acts'],
                        storfge['pmtc']])
```

Comment: сначало открываеи файл, парсим и записываем в цикле.

Comment: В списках первый элемент находиться по нулевому индексу . 'Резервы:' + ' ' + bidaq[0].text.strip()) и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


data = {
    'action': 'getrates',
    'page': 'list',
    'sort': 'reviews',
    'range': 'desc',
    'sortm': '0',
    'tsid': '0',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.bestchange.ru/action.php',  data=data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
block = (x.stripped_strings for x in soup('tr')[1:] if len(x) > 4)

with open('example.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    pisar = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    pisar.writerow(['Name', 'Reserv', 'Kurs', 'Wmbl', 'Acts', 'Pmtc'])

    for name, work, reserv, kurs, wmbl, acts, pmtc, *g in block:
        print(name, work, reserv, kurs, wmbl, acts, pmtc, ''.join(g),  sep=' | ')
        pisar.writerow([name, work, reserv, kurs, wmbl, acts, pmtc])
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!