# Cохранить данные в csv в виде таблицы

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, csv, bs4

Есть код

```
res = requests.get('https://pilomaterialov.net/vagonka/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

items_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="product-wrap b1c-good col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12")
for item in items_cards:
      product_name = item.find("h2", class_="product-name b1c-name").text.strip()
      price_for = item.find("div", class_="product-field-display").text.strip()
      product_price = item.find("span", class_="PricesalesPrice").text.strip()
      all_a = item.find("img", class_="browseProductImage").get("src")
      # print(f"title: {product_name} - price: {product_price} - price_fo
```

Как его сохранить в таблицу csv?
[image: пример]

Comment: Почитайте про `Pandas`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1515339/470333

Comment: выпил пива.....и о чудо....все сраслось)
всем огромный СЕНК!